# AWS-Java-SDK version issue with hadoop 2.7.7

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3, pyspark

i am running a simple spark app to get file from s3 in rdd and convert it into pyspark dataframe:

```
data=sc.textFile('s3a://bigdata-plat/churnData/transaction.csv')
df=data.toDF()
```

also tried,

```
data=sc.textFile('s3a://bigdata-plat/churnData/transaction.csv')
df = data.map(lambda x: Row(**f(x))).toDF()
```

but it gives same error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.TransferManager.<init>(Lcom/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3;Ljava/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor;)V
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.initialize(S3AFileSystem.java:287)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2667)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:93)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2701)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2683)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:372)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:258)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:229)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:315)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:204)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:253)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:251)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:253)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:251)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.partitions(JavaRDDLike.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.partitions(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

i am setting spark context as:

```
pyspark.SparkConf().setAll([('spark.eventLog.dir', '/spark/logs/tmp/')
            ,("spark.driver.extraClassPath","path/hadoop-common-2.7.7.jar:/path/aws-java-sdk-1.10.6.jar:path/hadoop-aws-2.7.7.jar")
            ,("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl","org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
                        ,("fs.s3a.access.key", AWS_ACCESS_KEY)
            ,("fs.s3a.secret.key", AWS_SECRET_KEY)])
```

I am using Spark 2.4 , hadoop 2.7.7

```
aws-java-sdk versions tried : 1.11.440, 1.11.75, 1.10.6, 1.7.4
```

i am unable to understand here is it dependency issue?
or i am missing any additional jar files that are needed?
any solution?

Answer (score 2):

The AWS SDKs are pretty brittle. You need to use the exact version of the AWS SDK the hadoop-aws connector was built with, otherwise things either don't link properly or fail in various ways.

For the files you need, see: 
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-aws/2.7.7

PS, no need to set spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl. That binding is automatic

Comment: I have tried using aws-java-sdk-1.7.4  on which my hadoop version is set.
but same error show up 
also for this version aws-java-sdk-bundle is not available 
and without  aws-java-sdk-bundle it gives the following error ::

 com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
        at com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProviderChain.getCredentials(AWSCredentialsProviderChain.java:117)

Comment: 1. avoid the bundle. Hadoop 2.9+ went to the full shaded bundle. Every update to the AWS SDK is trouble; usually at least 1+ regression to be fixed, filed with AWS, etc. 
2. authentication is a separate problem. For diagnosing those, start with [cloudstore](https://github.com/steveloughran/cloudstore/releases) for some basic filesystem operations on the hadoop command line. You can use that code from Spark too if you try hard enough.